# Can I get dummy iOS Keychain Access? for build phonegap verification

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I want to install my first mobile app in my iPhone 4. My problem is that while building the app for iOS, it will ask for developer certificate. 
So my question is, is there any way to get that certificate. I am not using Mac.

Answer (score 1):

So I suppose you are using PhoneGap Build to build your app since you don't even have Mac. So what you need is the certificate to sign your app with. It is nowadays possible to do that without Mac and there is tutorial [here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac).

What it basically tells you to do is to install [OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), run the appropriate commands to create the Certificate Signing Request (CSR) which should be about the same as when using Mac. After this the CSR needs to be sent to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action) to get the signed certificate which is then uploaded to the PhoneGap Build accompanied by the provision file created at the Developer center.

Comment: Thank you San, while walking through the 3rd step my cmd throwing an error: unknown option -subj "/emailAddress=myEmail@gmail.com, CN=myname, C=IND"                          any idea about it?

Comment: I'm sorry for that, it's working fine when i restart my mission and do the same, little strange And again do we need to pay sum to apple for the login and getting the certificate?

Comment: As far as I know, yes you need to because they (Apple) need to sign the signing request you generate.

Comment: can u see this...  http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/step2/Exporting-the-App/

Comment: @Shaw: Well, that is someone else's certificate you are using on that case and it must match your app id (which in that case must be `om.gamevil.zenonia2`). I'm not quite sure if that is going to work with PhoneGap Build but change your id in _config.xml_ and give it a chance. I am not completely sure about how Apple feels about it, though.

Comment: And how did your _widget_ tag look in the _config.xml_ when you tried?